# image could not be embedded when sending using php mail function

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have a problem when using the PHP mailer. I try to send an email which embedded by a logo after the last sentence (greetings) but the code did not work. by other means, the mail could not display the logo that I send.

here is the code, maybe you all could help

```
$mail ->Body = "Dear Mr/Mrs. $appname<br>
                CONGRATULATIONS!<br><br>  
                We are very interested by your previous experiences. We will 
                held an interview with you next Tuesday at 10 a.m<br>
                Best regards,<br> HR Team <br><img src='PHPMailer- 
                master/logo.png'>";
```

Is there anything wrong with this code?

```
<img src='PHPMailer-master/logo.png'>
```

Comment: *"Is there anything wrong with this code?"* - No and yes. "No", if it's local to you. "Yes": people don't have that folder and image on their computer; use a full external URL.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I already use the URL, it has the same result. Zero

Comment: update your post to contain what you used; we/I don't know what you're actually using as one (URL). Use error proper handling also.

Comment: You can embed the image in the message and refer to it from your HTML. Look at `addEmbeddedImage()`.